# Find the nearest point from a given point in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, geospatial

I have a set of points from which I created a multipoint.

```
SET @multi_point = ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(-118.2845938 34.0252385, -118.2867610 34.0221188, -118.2905912 34.0227248, -118.284119 34.021846, -118.2864676 34.0186438, -118.2886342 34.0203211, -118.2907290 34.0193680, -118.2831326 34.0192874, -118.2828242 34.0205473)');
```

I also have a single other point

```
SET @home = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.2819136 34.0261177)')
```

From `@home` I want to find the nearest 3 points. that are a part of the multi-point `@multi_point`. I thought of first determining the distance from this point @home to every point in the multipoint using `ST_DISTANCE`. But I get the following:

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(@home, @multi_point)

+----------------------------------+
| ST_DISTANCE(@home, @multi_point) |
+----------------------------------+
|            0.0028207205958764945 |
+----------------------------------+
```

It looks like I only get the *shortest distance* of the point to the multipoint. Questions:

1. Is there a way to get the shortest distance to every point, and determine the points themselves?
2. Is there a better way to determine the nearest neighbors from one point `@home` to the rest in `@multi_point`?

**EDIT** I tried Paul Spiegel's of storing these points in a table. But when I store a `Point` type, it is stored as a garbage value:

```
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Name            | Coordinates               |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| P1              |        [2]pxA@            |
| p2              |        +1Z]:PA@           |
| p3              |        a]KA@              |
| p4              |        X ]qgpA@           |
| p5              |        EW3|U]A@           |
| p6              |        M]bKzA@            |
| p7              |        Ku/]2ƇA@           |
| p9              |        =];A@              |
| p8              |        u`x]A@             |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

Also, When I query it, the distances are null.

```
SELECT P.Name, ST_DISTANCE(@home, P.Coordinates) AS dist 
FROM Placemark P ORDER BY dist LIMIT 3;

+--------------+------+
| Name         | dist |
+--------------+------+
| p1           | NULL |
| p2           | NULL |
| p3           | NULL |
+--------------+------+
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you save the points in a table with one row per point?

Comment: Sure. That would be fine.

Comment: Then the solution would be obvious: `SELECT p.*, ST_DISTANCE(@home, p.point) as dist FROM points p ORDER BY dist LIMIT 3`.

Comment: Okay. So storing the Point itself yeilds a fairly straightforward answer. Can you do something like that _without_ storing these points?

Comment: Where do the points come from? Maybe you can store them in a temporary table.

Comment: I made an edit. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using a temporary table:

```
drop temporary table if exists Placemark;
create temporary table Placemark(
    Name varchar(50),
    Coordinates point
);

insert into Placemark(Name, Coordinates) values
    ('p1', POINT(-118.2845938, 34.0252385)),
    ('p2', POINT(-118.2867610, 34.0221188)),
    ('p3', POINT(-118.2905912, 34.0227248)),
    ('p4', POINT(-118.284119 , 34.021846 )),
    ('p5', POINT(-118.2864676, 34.0186438)),
    ('p6', POINT(-118.2886342, 34.0203211)),
    ('p7', POINT(-118.2907290, 34.0193680)),
    ('p8', POINT(-118.2831326, 34.0192874)),
    ('p9', POINT(-118.2828242, 34.0205473));

SET @home = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.2819136 34.0261177)');

SELECT 
    P.Name,
    ST_AsText(P.Coordinates) as Coordinates,
    ST_DISTANCE(@home, P.Coordinates) AS dist 
FROM Placemark P
ORDER BY dist
LIMIT 3
```

The result:

```
Name | Coordinates                    | dist
p1   | POINT(-118.2845938 34.0252385) | 0.00282072059587649
p4   | POINT(-118.284119 34.021846)   | 0.00480741199088132
p9   | POINT(-118.2828242 34.0205473) | 0.00564433773972052
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GMPK57301

To define a POINT use either `POINT(-118.2845938, 34.0252385)` or `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-118.2845938 34.0252385)')`. To see the value in a readable form use `ST_AsText()`.

Comment: This doesn't actually do KNN at all.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - What is *KNN* for you - And how does it relate to OP's question?

Comment: KNN is an algorithm, it isn't a "for me" thing. But, I did clarify here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/214354/2639. FYI I didn't downvote or anything. This will work to find the nearest row based on the distance from the prior row. It just doesn't have anything to do with KNN.